# Record video on android

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to record video following this guide MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent. When I use my ASUS ZenFone 2 it works ok and video succesfully record. But when I try use it on Micromax Canvas without SD card I get "No external memory available" error. Also I tried to put extra to point internal memory:

```
private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    File videoFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "\video.mp4");
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile)); 
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

But error "No external memory available" still remains.
If I pass Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT I also get "No external memory available" on phone that has no sd card(or emulated sd card) How can I solve this?

Comment: Neither your app nor the app handling `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` has any access to `getDataDirectory()` on any Android device.

Comment: Do you want to store video on External storage?

Comment: try this,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead Environment.getDataDirectory()

Comment: If I pass Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT I also get "No external memory available" on phone that has no sd card(or emulated sd card)